# Анаконда 3 на Анаконда 2

Tags: python, установка

Если уже стоит Анаконда с Python 2.7, а нужен еще и Python 3.6 - как поставить Анаконду 3? Просто ставим Анаконду 3 поверх Анаконды 2? Или есть какая-то хитрость?

Comment: Ставите Анаконда 3 и у нее будет отдельная папка, поверх не будет ставиться

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо, попробую.
Пока попробовал поставить новое окружение с Python 3.6 к уже имеющемуся пакету с Python 2.7 через `conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda`, но не могу запустить это новое окружение. Буду пробовать дальше.

Comment: Поставил рядом. Работает. Спасибо.

Comment: через новое окружение, кстати, тоже запустилось